# How do I insert into sql and skip what already exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to duplicate records in a table and the new records have a new CompanyID everything else is the same.  Some of the records already exists and cause my script not to run.  How can I skip the records that already exists?

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM UserRole WHERE 
CompanyID = @oldComp;
ALTER TABLE #TempTable DROP COLUMN id;
UPDATE #TempTable SET CompanyID = @newComp;
INSERT INTO UserRole SELECT * FROM #TempTable;
DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

Comment: `Left Join` with `where joinedtableid is null`.

Comment: Your code does not make sense to me.  You insert N columns into the temp table from `UserRole`.  But, at the end, you insert N-1 columns into `UserRole` from the temp table.

Comment: Use `SELECT * FROM #TempTable WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)` to exclude existing rows from the query

Comment: Are there many columns? By specifying the columns explicitly, you can do this in one statement without temp table.

Comment: Is `COLUMN id` in table `UserRole` set to use **AUTO INCREMENT** also known as **IDENTITY** (assuming it is an INT)?

Comment: @PeterB yea thats why i have the drop in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just use `UPDATE` statement :

```
UPDATE UserRole 
     SET CompanyID = @newComp
WHERE CompanyID = @oldComp;
```

**EDIT :** If you want to insert new records then you use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
INSERT INTO UserRole (col1, col2, . . .) 
     SELECT t.col1, t.col2, . . . 
     FROM #TempTable t
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UserRole U WHERE u.col = t.col);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what all the column names are, but if you are willing/able to list them out, then maybe a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` would do here:

```
INSERT INTO UserRole (CompanyID, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT @newComp, col1, col2, col3
FROM UserRole
WHERE CompanyID = @oldComp;
```

If the new company ID already might appear in certain records, and you want to avoid inserting new records which might have the same value in all other columns, then add an `EXISTS` clause to the above query:

```
INSERT INTO UserRole (CompanyID, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT @newComp, u1.col1, u1.col2, u1.col3
FROM UserRole u1
WHERE
    CompanyID = @oldComp AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UserRole u2
                WHERE u1.col1 = u2.col1 AND u1.col2 = u2.col2 AND u1.col3 = u2.col3 AND
                      u2.CompanyID = @newComp);
```

Comment: And then still  use `where not exists` to exclude the existing rows, which was the actual reason for the question.

Comment: @GolezTrol I added an update to cover this possibility, but I'm not sure this exists for the OP.  It sounds to me like the OP just wants to generate new records which don't already exist logically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TempTable 
FROM UserRole 
WHERE CompanyID = @oldComp;

ALTER TABLE #TempTable DROP COLUMN id;

UPDATE #TempTable SET CompanyID = @newComp;

INSERT INTO UserRole 
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM UserRole

DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

The `EXCEPT` statement below:

```
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM UserRole
```

will give you all records from the `#TempTable` that do not exists in the target table.

Comment: Could be a good approach, if there is no surrogate key/auto-increment field, because if so, the rows in #temptable won't match the existing rows UserRole.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes, you are right. But if there is such key, you are not allowed to populate its value, so it just can be excluded from the `SELECT`.